# Validating InputVerifier from GUI Builder

Tags: java, swing, validation, user-interface

I created some `JTextFields` and `JComboBox` using Gui Builder(Drag and drop) and added a submit trigger `JButton`. I wanted to validate the Swing Controls by checking if textfields are empty calling the method `verify()` in my GUI.

**validation class**

```
public class validation extends InputVerifier
{
  @Override
  public boolean verify(JComponent input) 
  {
    String text = null;
    String cb = null;

    if(input instanceof JTextField)
    {
        text = ((JTextField) input).getText();
    }
    else if(input instanceof JComboBox)
    {
        cb = ((JComboBox) input).getSelectedItem().toString();
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

**AddEmployee**

I already created a instance of my class validation.

```
public class AddEmployee extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame{

/**
 * Creates new form AddEmployee
 */
validation v = new validation();

   private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
      String lastName = tfLastName.getText();
      String firstName = tfFirstName.getText();

      tfLastName.setName("lastName");
      tfFirstName.setName("firstName");

      v.verify(tfLastName,tfFirstName);
   }

}//end of AddEmployee
```

When I'm trying to passed the variable names of my `JTextFields` in `verify()` method it throws me a error.

> no suitable method found for verify(JTextFields,JTextFields) method InputVerifier.verify is not applicable

What I did I created a void method `verify()` under **validation** class.

```
public void verify(JTextField tfLastName, JTextField tfFirstName) {

}
```

**Question**

- Where should I validate textfields? Should I validate under **AddEmployee** or **validation** class?

Any help or tips I would greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can find InputVerifier usage and purpose [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice: when you create the `JTextField` assign the verifier to it:

```
  tfLastName.setInputVerifier(new validation());
```

BTW: Use correct java naming convention:  **V**alidation

Comment: Where I'm gonna include the validation for my `JTextFields`?

Comment: "when you create the `JTextField` " . For more detailed help post an [MCVE]